# quickSort javaScript throwing Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, quicksort, callstack

**why is this function throwing error**

I am trying to sort array using quickSort with a recursion approach
here I am using the last element in the array as a pivot

```
let array = [1,0,123,1,3,12,2,45,6]
function quickSort(array, leastIndex, highIndex) {
    if (leastIndex >= highIndex) return;

    const pivot = array[highIndex];
    let leftPointer = leastIndex;
    let rightPointer = highIndex;

    while (leftPointer < rightPointer) {
        while (array[leftPointer] <= pivot && leftPointer < rightPointer) {
            leftPointer++;
        }
        while (array[rightPointer] >= pivot && rightPointer > leftPointer) {
            rightPointer--;
        }
        swap(array, leftPointer, rightPointer)
    }
    swap(array, leftPointer, highIndex);
    quickSort(array, leastIndex, leftPointer);
    quickSort(array, leftPointer + 1, highIndex);
}

function swap(array, a, b) {
    let temp = array[a]
    array[a] = array[b]
    array[b] = temp
}
quickSort(array,0,array.length-1)
console.log(array);
```

**ERROR**

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at swap (<anonymous>:23:14)
    at quickSort (<anonymous>:16:9)
    at quickSort (<anonymous>:19:5)
    at quickSort (<anonymous>:19:5)
    at quickSort (<anonymous>:19:5)
    at quickSort (<anonymous>:19:5)
    at quickSort (<anonymous>:19:5)
    at quickSort (<anonymous>:19:5)
    at quickSort (<anonymous>:19:5)
    at quickSort (<anonymous>:19:5)
```

Comment: Please add the error to the question so other members can help you.

Comment: You want the solution with the proper answer on how to do it or us to fix this one?

Comment: Fix this one, please

Comment: In that way you have a Stack Overflow ;p which means that your stopping point never happens and it keeps running.

Comment: I am not able to figure out what is causing the error

Comment: You built it in a really complicated way that's hard for me to follow on what's going on sorry :/

Comment: I know what is a quick sort and how to make one in js but not in that way ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the pivot is also the greatest value, that the first recursive call will be made with exactly the same range again, and so the partition to sort isn't becoming smaller...

Since your version of Quicksort ensures that you have the index of the pivot value (after the final swap), you can *exclude* that value from further recursive calls. So change:

```
quickSort(array, leastIndex, leftPointer);
```

to:

```
quickSort(array, leastIndex, leftPointer - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
quickSort(array, leastIndex, leftPointer);
```

It should be

```
quickSort(array, leastIndex, leftPointer - 1);
```